# Apps compatible with iPhone5 and reverse

Tags: iphone, iphone-5

I know that an app developed for iPhones older than iPhone5 is working in a letter box.
But how about the revers. An app updated to iPhone5 standard. How does it work on iPhone4 ?

If not, when all developers have updated their apps, the older iPhones will be without apps or updates ?

Comment: This is under NDA right now - check out the Apple Dev forums. There's some Q&A on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more geared toward MonoTouch, but the same techniques apply to Obj-C:

http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/

Basically the Default-568h@2x.png file will tell iOS that it's a 'Tall' app.  For other image assets you need to detect if it's the tall device or not by checking the UIScreen's MainScreen's Bounds as well as if it's an iPhone idiom or not and then seeing if the height is 1136 (checking the scale value), and then selecting a different sized image in this case.

Here's the C# code, but again it's very close to Obj-C:

```
public static bool IsTall
{
  get 
  { 
    return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom 
             == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone 
           && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height 
             * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale >= 1136;
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. The tall default picture I found out myself just by trying that the first thing after updated Xcode to latest version. Just by dragging such a picture to the rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an image called Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136) to your project and like magic it will work! It's unbelievable how easy it is.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is like magic. Typically Apple. Other ViewControllers with xib and scrolling windows are a little bit more tricky I guess but for just a table is really easy.

Comment: Yes other stuff can be tricky, but for my map that contains mapviews and table views, it did the trick with absolutely no other adjustment!

Answer (score 1):

They will need to adjust their layout accordingly using AutoLayout or something similar.

Answer (score -2):

Of course they will work.
If you don't code them to automatically shrink or use smaller images, then it'll just get cut off top or bottom.